# How can I get soft deleted entity from typeorm postgreSQL?

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, express, typeorm

I am trying to get soft deleted doc from `postgreSQL` database using `typeorm` `find, findOne or query builder get/getMany` methods, but it always return undefined. Is there a way to get deleted value?

By the docs it should only set a timestamp for `deletedAt`, and it definitely works, because I can update same record using update where from query builder.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I found out there is another solution. You can use the querybuilders `.withDeleted()` method to also return soft deleted entities.

Example

```
 const query = await this.manager
        .getRepository(FolderEntity)
        .withDeleted() 
        .createQueryBuilder('folder')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('folder.subStatus', 'status')
        .getMany()
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks. Would've helped me when I needed it, but I will definitely remember it later on :)

Answer (score 18):

Actually referring to the [findOptions doc](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md) you can pass the `withDeleted` boolean that will retrieve the soft deleted rows.

for example:

```
const result = await this.repo.find({ where: { id }, withDeleted: true })
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `find` or `findOne`, you can do it with:

```js
import { IsNull, Not } from 'typeorm';

//...
this.yourRepository.find({
  where: {
    deletedAt: Not(IsNull()),
  },
  withDeleted: true,
});
```

Which I think is elegant, easy to read and avoids using the query builder, which is probably not widely used in your code.

Answer (score 0):

After more searching I found that only solution is to use raw sql query for that as it is shown in [typeorm docs](https://typeorm.io/#/entity-manager-api) at the query block.

```
const deletedEntity = await connection
    .getRepository(Entity)
    .query(`SELECT * FROM Entity where id = '${deletedEntityId}'`)
```

This query returns values with deletedAt timestamp.

Comment: This is odd. Your proposed solution is not the _only_ solution

Comment: Yes, I've proposed a solution that I've found by myself, but after the month the better answer came and I accepted the new one by @BunyamiN as the better one.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const queryBuilder = await this.yourRepository.createQueryBuilder('entity');
queryBuilder.withDeleted();
queryBuilder.where(`entity.deleted_at IS NOT NULL`)};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
await getManager().transaction(async (em) => {
    await em.update(Faqs, { id }, { updatedAt: userId });
    await em.softDelete(Faqs, id);
});
```